# MySql Transpose Row into Column and Column into Row

Tags: mysql, sql, transpose

i have problem with transposing row to column and column to row.
I can do that if it just transpose row to column or column to row.

This my table with data

```
UNIT|JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MEI|JUN
CS-1|100|200|300|400|500|600
CS-2|111|222|333|444|555|666
CS-3|331|123|423|923|918|123
```

and I would like to get the following output

```
MONTH|CS-1|CS-2|CS-3
JAN  |100 |111 |331
FEB  |200 |222 |123
MAR  |300 |333 |423
```

etc..

Anybody know how to do this? Thanks very much!

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. Assuming you really have a proper  table here there will be an arbitrary number of rows, to become an arbitrary number of columns. Mysql has limits on the number of columns you can have. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
SELECT month,
       MAX(CASE WHEN unit = 'CS-1' THEN value END) `CS-1`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN unit = 'CS-2' THEN value END) `CS-2`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN unit = 'CS-3' THEN value END) `CS-3`
  FROM
(
  SELECT unit, month,
         CASE month 
            WHEN 'JAN' THEN jan
            WHEN 'FEB' THEN feb
            WHEN 'MAR' THEN mar
            WHEN 'APR' THEN apr
            WHEN 'MAY' THEN may
            WHEN 'JUN' THEN jun
         END value
    FROM table1 t CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT 'JAN' month UNION ALL
    SELECT 'FEB' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'MAR' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'APR' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'MAY' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'JUN'
  ) c
) q
 GROUP BY month
 ORDER BY FIELD(month, 'JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN')
```

Output:

```
| MONTH | CS-1 | CS-2 | CS-3 |
|-------|------|------|------|
|   JAN |  100 |  111 |  331 |
|   FEB |  200 |  222 |  123 |
|   MAR |  300 |  333 |  423 |
|   APR |  400 |  444 |  923 |
|   MAY |  500 |  555 |  918 |
|   JUN |  600 |  666 |  123 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cc06/5)** demo