# Value as column name in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

How to query SQL to convert key-value table to a bunch of column whose name is the key, and the value is the value?

I.E.

```
owner  | key    | value
----------------------------
   1   | AGE    | 15
   1   | HEIGHT | 155
   1   | WHAT   | Nothing
   1   | WHAT   | Something
```

to something like this:

```
owner  | AGE    | HEIGHT  | WHAT
----------------------------
   1   | 15     | 155     | Nothing;Something
```

I had a query which done it manually, is there a way to keep it generic?
Thanks.

Comment: You are unnecessarily wasting space in the second case. Why would you want this? Any specific reason / use case?

Comment: @VaradBhatnagar I'm using the second table to index it to ElasticSearch. Also I changed it a bit, look at edited

Comment: There is something known as long form and wide form of data .Functions melt and cast are used in R . They are used to convert between the two tables that you have given. Try searching for something equivalent in SQL.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19019453/1271037, https://stackoverflow.com/q/16568228/1271037, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3392956/1271037 and more.