# Order Results by a Column’s Rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

The reply selected as the best answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019453/mysql-transpose-row-into-column-and-column-into-row) was helpful. But, it seems “ORDER BY FIELD” is not supported in SQLite.

Using [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cc06/5), how can I set a specific order to the rows in the Month column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `ORDER BY FIELD` in SQLite.
Instead you can do it with conditional ordering:

```
ORDER BY CASE month
    WHEN 'JAN' THEN 1
    WHEN 'FEB' THEN 2
    WHEN 'MAR' THEN 3
    WHEN 'APR' THEN 4
    WHEN 'MAY' THEN 5
    WHEN 'JUN' THEN 6
END
```

or by using `INSTR()`:

```
ORDER BY INSTR('JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN', month)
```

you can omit the commas or replace with any other separator.

Comment: seams when i read the documentation SQLite [INSTR](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr) it seams its not a total drop in replacement for MySQL's [FIELD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)... Seams INSTR does not work on numeric datatype where FIELD does, but i know SQLite is a loose typed database just like MySQL.. The SQLite devs most likely forgot to mention in the manual that the function does with numeric datatypes as most likely it would work.

Comment: INSTR is a string function. The way I use it to simulate FIELD is just a trick. But it does work also for numeric values: `select instr('15,25,35', 25)` will return 4.

Comment: yes offcource the (two) input params are only strings not just like MySQL's "endless" param FIELD input..