# Unknown Syntax Error While Trying to Pivot Table in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb, syntax-error, pivot-table, transpose

I am trying to transform a table of data--I want ALL of the rows to become the columns, and ALL of the columns to become the rows, effectively swapping them. I am using the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019453/mysql-transpose-row-into-column-and-column-into-row) to do so.

If it makes any difference, I am running my own MariaDB server on a Raspberry Pi (I have very little data) using PHPMyAdmin.

The table (truncated) looks like this:

```
Personality|Abby|Aidan|Brandon|Bobby
Agreeabl...|93  |65   |74     |68
Compassion |95  |65   |96     |96
Politeness |81  |9    |21     |12
Conscient..|45  |13   |99     |28
```

I'm trying to transpose it into this:

```
Coach  |Agreeableness|Compassion|Politeness|Conscientiousness
Abby   |93           |95        |81        |45
Aidan  |65           |96        |9         |13 
Brandon|74           |96        |21        |99
Bobby  |68           |96        |12        |28
```

And my query is here:

```
SELECT Coach,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Agreeableness' THEN value END) `Agreeableness`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Compassion' THEN value END) `Compassion`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Politeness' THEN value END) `Politeness`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Conscientiousness' THEN value END) `Conscientiousness`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Industriousness' THEN value END) `Industriousness`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Orderliness' THEN value END) `Orderliness`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Extraversion' THEN value END) `Extraversion`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Enthusiasm' THEN value END) `Enthusiasm`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Assertiveness' THEN value END) `Assertiveness`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Neuroticism' THEN value END) `Neuroticism`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Withdrawal' THEN value END) `Withdrawal`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Volatility' THEN value END) `Volatility`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Openness' THEN value END) `Openness`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Intellect' THEN value END) `Intellect`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Openness (Aspect)' THEN value END) `Openness (Aspect)`
  FROM 
(
  SELECT Personality, Coach,
         CASE Coach
            WHEN 'Abby' THEN Abby
            WHEN 'Aidan' THEN Aidan
            WHEN 'Brandon' THEN Brandon
            WHEN 'Bobby' THEN Bobby
            WHEN 'Carlos' THEN Carlos
            WHEN 'Carrie' THEN Carrie
            WHEN 'Chassidy' THEN Chassidy
            WHEN 'Emily' THEN Emily
            WHEN 'Galen' THEN Galen
            WHEN 'Gavin' THEN Gavin
            **WHEN 'Grant' THEN Grant** #part of interest
            WHEN 'Greg' THEN Greg
            WHEN 'Jack' THEN Jack
            WHEN 'Jenn' THEN Jenn
            WHEN 'Noah' THEN Noah
            WHEN 'Mae' THEN Mae
            WHEN 'Patrick' THEN Patrick
            WHEN 'Titus' THEN Titus
         END value 
    FROM table1 t CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT 'Abby' Coach UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Aidan' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Brandon' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Bobby' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Carlos' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Carrie' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Chassidy' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Emily' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Galen' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Gavin' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Grant' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Greg' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jack' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jenn' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Noah' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mae' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Patrick' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Titus' UNION ALL
 ) c    
) q 
 GROUP BY Coach
 ORDER BY FIELD(Coach, 'Abby', 'Aidan', 'Brandon', 'Bobby', 'Carlos', 'Carrie', 'Chassidy', 'Emily', 'Galen', 'Gavin', 'Grant', 'Greg', 'Jack', 'Jenn', 'Noah', 'Mae', 'Patrick', 'Titus');
```

I am getting this error while running it:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') c    
) q
GROUP BY Coach
ORDER BY FIELD(Coach, 'Abby', 'Aidan', 'Bran...' at line 60
```

I do not really know what my code is doing, and what the "table t1" cross join and "c" and "q" subqueries really mean, so I don't know how to fix the error.

P.S. My new column names in the large "CASE Coach" statement are in backticks ` because one of the names has to be Grant but that's a SQL keyword. I've been told that's how to fix that problem.

Comment: I just changed "table 1 t" to 'TABLE 2' t since that's what the table is called in my database--didn't fix anything, however.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56670844/1766831

Answer (score 0):

Delete last `UNION ALL` from `c` like this;

```
SELECT Coach,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Agreeableness' THEN value END) `Agreeableness`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Compassion' THEN value END) `Compassion`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Politeness' THEN value END) `Politeness`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Conscientiousness' THEN value END) `Conscientiousness`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Industriousness' THEN value END) `Industriousness`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Orderliness' THEN value END) `Orderliness`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Extraversion' THEN value END) `Extraversion`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Enthusiasm' THEN value END) `Enthusiasm`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Assertiveness' THEN value END) `Assertiveness`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Neuroticism' THEN value END) `Neuroticism`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Withdrawal' THEN value END) `Withdrawal`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Volatility' THEN value END) `Volatility`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Openness' THEN value END) `Openness`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Intellect' THEN value END) `Intellect`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Personality = 'Openness (Aspect)' THEN value END) `Openness (Aspect)`
  FROM 
(
  SELECT Personality, Coach,
         CASE Coach
            WHEN 'Abby' THEN Abby
            WHEN 'Aidan' THEN Aidan
            WHEN 'Brandon' THEN Brandon
            WHEN 'Bobby' THEN Bobby
            WHEN 'Carlos' THEN Carlos
            WHEN 'Carrie' THEN Carrie
            WHEN 'Chassidy' THEN Chassidy
            WHEN 'Emily' THEN Emily
            WHEN 'Galen' THEN Galen
            WHEN 'Gavin' THEN Gavin
            **WHEN 'Grant' THEN Grant** #part of interest
            WHEN 'Greg' THEN Greg
            WHEN 'Jack' THEN Jack
            WHEN 'Jenn' THEN Jenn
            WHEN 'Noah' THEN Noah
            WHEN 'Mae' THEN Mae
            WHEN 'Patrick' THEN Patrick
            WHEN 'Titus' THEN Titus
         END value 
    FROM table1 t CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT 'Abby' Coach UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Aidan' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Brandon' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Bobby' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Carlos' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Carrie' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Chassidy' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Emily' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Galen' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Gavin' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Grant' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Greg' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jack' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jenn' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Noah' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mae' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Patrick' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Titus'
 ) c    
) q 
 GROUP BY Coach
 ORDER BY FIELD(Coach, 'Abby', 'Aidan', 'Brandon', 'Bobby', 'Carlos', 'Carrie', 'Chassidy', 'Emily', 'Galen', 'Gavin', 'Grant', 'Greg', 'Jack', 'Jenn', 'Noah', 'Mae', 'Patrick', 'Titus');
```

Document about `UNION ALL` is [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/union/)